# How can I get the value of a key which is into a hash that is into params hash in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

When I edit the values using a form, rails calls update method and makes the following hash. How can I get the value of  `v_tipo_control_id` which is into the `f_controls_attributes`'s hash? The `f_controls` values are got using `fields_to`.

```
  Processing by TLogicaldevicesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PqSHE3BAXUfcIN0MDh7AWnPT4HyGMpGKW9TkezArK2xJavrqSOUc7l5wnGX3XXVJp6M0prNp7pZZiVTYzmHc4g==", 
     "t_logicaldevice"=>{"f_element_id"=>"43", 
       "f_controls_attributes"=>
                {
                 "0"=>{"v_tipo_control_id"=>"1", "hour_start_on"=>"", "v_ortoocaso_id_on"=>"",
                 "v_magnitudrep_id_on"=>"", "v_tipoejecucion_id_on"=>"",
                "off_set_on"=>"", "repeat_on"=>"", "rep_offset_on"=>"", "v_accion_id"=>""}}},
                  "total_controles"=>"2", "commit"=>"Guardar", "id"=>"75"
              }
```

I try:

```
params[:f_controls][:v_tipo_control_id] 

params[:f_controls_attributes]
```

but both show `f_controls` as `nil` so I can't get `v_tipo_control_id` value.

### Update:

That works! Thanks mudasobwa. But the problem is if I have some f_controls like...

```
"f_controls_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{"f_element_id"=>"", "v_tipo_control_id"=>"3", "hour_start_on"=>"", "v_ortoocaso_id_on"=>"", 
           "v_magnitudrep_id_on"=>"", "v_tipoejecucion_id_on"=>"", "off_set_on"=>"", "repeat_on"=>"", "rep_offset_on"=>"", 
     "v_accion_id"=>"", "id"=>"106"}, 
    "1"=>{"f_element_id"=>"", "v_tipo_control_id"=>"1", "hour_start_on"=>"", "v_ortoocaso_id_on"=>"", 
        "v_magnitudrep_id_on"=>"", "v_tipoejecucion_id_on"=>"", "off_set_on"=>"", "repeat_on"=>"", "rep_offset_on"=>"", 
     "v_accion_id"=>"", "id"=>"107"}}}
```

In this example I have two f_control hashes. Do I have to write the number value manual? Is there any other form more automatically? Because not always I know the exactly number of f_control.

Actually, when there are serveral, I need to know the ones that I update only. But I don't know if there is any option to know that. Is there any option?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the `update` and `strong_params` methods?

Comment: nesi: please format your code, so that it's all visible without having to scroll horizontally

Comment: Which `v_tipo_control_id` would you like to get if there are several?

Comment: Actually, when there are serveral, I need to know the ones that I update only.  But I don't know if there is any option to know that.

Comment: Please consider selecting the one and only remaining answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters have strings as keys, you are trying to access them using symbols. Unless you have a hash with indifferent access, that won’t work:

```
▶ params['t_logicaldevice']['f_controls_attributes']['0']['v_tipo_control_id']
#⇒ "1"
```

To receive all values:

```
▶ params['t_logicaldevice']['f_controls_attributes'].values.map do |e|
▷   e['v_tipo_control_id']
▷ end
#⇒ [
#  [0] "1",
#  [1] "1"
# ]
```

Comment: rails params _are_ with indifferent access.